Can I integrate zap with karate framework?
I am starting to perform automated tests to apis in a project,
I would like to run security validations like the ones done with the owasp zap scanner, but immersed in my karate automation. That is to say that when consuming an owasp api performs automated validations.
Do you know if this can be done?
if you have any guide that you can provide me I would appreciate it very much!

public class ActiveScan {

    private static final int ZAP_PORT = 8080;
    private static final String ZAP_API_KEY = null;
    private static final String ZAP_ADDRESS = "localhost";
    private static final String TARGET = "https://public-firing-range.appspot.com";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ClientApi api = new ClientApi(ZAP_ADDRESS, ZAP_PORT, ZAP_API_KEY);

        try {
            // TODO : explore the app (Spider, etc) before using the Active Scan API, Refer the explore section
            System.out.println("Active Scanning target : " + TARGET);
            ApiResponse resp = api.ascan.scan(TARGET, "True", "False", null, null, null);
            String scanid;
            int progress;

            // The scan now returns a scan id to support concurrent scanning
            scanid = ((ApiResponseElement) resp).getValue();
            // Poll the status until it completes
            while (true) {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                progress =
                        Integer.parseInt(
                                ((ApiResponseElement) api.ascan.status(scanid)).getValue());
                System.out.println("Active Scan progress : " + progress + "%");
                if (progress >= 100) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Active Scan complete");
            // Print vulnerabilities found by the scanning
            System.out.println("Alerts:");
            System.out.println(new String(api.core.xmlreport(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

You can write a java utility and call it in feature file. The above code is do an active scan, taken from documentation. Just give a try. Documentation linK: https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/api/?java#using-active-scan

Its worth noting that this code on its own will do nothing, unless you have already proxied requests through ZAP. You can also explore you app via the 2 ZAP spiders, or via importing API definitions. Lots more docs here: https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/
